# ¿Por qué no cambia el State con el onClick?

Tags: reactjs

Si en vez de un elemento `li` pongo un Select con options ahí si funciona pero con `li` no, ¿es solo por la etiqueta?

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'

const useCategoria = ( stateInicial, opciones ) => {

  const [ state, setState ] = useState(stateInicial)


  const Categoria = () => (
    <ol className=" flex cursor-pointer pt-2 mr-20 sm:mr-12 md:mr-24 overflow-x-auto">
        {opciones.map( opcion => (
            <li onClick={ e => setState(e.target.value)} className="px-1 font-bold text-slate-400 md:text-white hover:text-red-600" key={opcion.value} value={opcion.value}>{opcion.title}</li>
        ))}
    </ol>
  )

  return [ state, Categoria ];

}
 
export default useCategoria;
```

Comment: cual es el estado inicial?

Comment: será porque los `<li>` no tienen una propiedad `value` y los `option` del `select` si?

Answer (score 0):

La etiqueta li no tiene la propiedad value puedes mejor cambiar el código y realizar algo parecido a esto

```
const Categoria = () => (
    <ol className=" flex cursor-pointer pt-2 mr-20 sm:mr-12 md:mr-24 overflow-x-auto">
        {opciones.map( opcion => (
            <li onClick={ () => setState(opcion.value) } className="px-1 font-bold text-slate-400 md:text-white hover:text-red-600" key={opcion.value}>{opcion.title}</li>
        ))}
    </ol>
  )
```